# Are values required for attributes in HTML5?

Tags: html

The question is illustrated below:

```
<ul data-my-div='true><li></li></ul> <!-- this is surely okay -->
<ul data-my-div><li></li></ul> <!-- but is this? -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test it! See, e.g. [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLQtE/). Short tests showed, that you can use in at least Firefox and Chrome.

```
<ul id="t1" data-my-div="true"><li></li></ul>
<ul id="t2" data-my-div><li></li></ul>


<div id="r1"></div>
<div id="r2"></div>

<script>
document.querySelector( '#r1' ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify( document.querySelector( '#t1' ).dataset );

document.querySelector( '#r2' ).innerHTML = JSON.stringify( document.querySelector( '#t2' ).dataset );
```

result:

> {"myDiv":"true"}
>
> {"myDiv":""}

In general, the reference explicitly allows for empty attributes [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty):

> **empty attribute syntax**
>
> Certain attributes may be specified by providing just the attribute name, with no value.

Comment: thx, i know i need to read those. i checked the w3c css one and it was huge. huge! so its not easy to know where to start. anyway, i have seen disabled used before and i know i can get away with it. but even that doc did not get any more specific than "certain". well does that mean what i did was okay or not?

Comment: @user1757120 In my experience it is OK, but to be certain I personally tend to use styles like `data-flag="true"` to circumvent any browser inconsistencies in parsing.

Comment: "*Certain* attributes may ..." really isn't very helpful, is it? [The Spec itself](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#attributes-0) has no such "Certain" qualifier, so yes data-* attributes with-out an explicit value are allowed. Good answer (+1)

Comment: outstanding, thx. was appropriately explained in the "Empty attribute syntax" section.